# NSMutableArray Issue.What i am missing?

Tags: ios4

### Here is my array:

---

MyTestArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Who invented america?",@"Fredrick",@"Colob bas",@"Alfred Novel",@"Sohel",nil];

### I want to print it as follows :

---

NSLog(@"%@",[MyTestArray objectAtIndex:0]);

What i did wrong here?I just wanted to get value at the index.But my program is crashing here.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to check. what is the variable `MyTestArray` declared as? It should be declared as NSMutableArray.

UPDATED:
This is a memory problem. Are you retaining your `MyTestArray`? `arrayWithObjects:` method return an autorelease object. So it might only be valid for the current loop and being released when the next loop begin.

There's several way to retain object. I always recommend using property but for you it can be as simple as doing this.

```
MyTestArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Who invented america?",@"Fredrick",@"Colob bas",@"Alfred Novel",@"Sohel",nil] retain];
```

Shouldn't crash now.

Comment: @interface GameTableView : UITableViewController {
 
    NSMutableArray *MyTestArray;
 
}

Comment: it's declared as NSMutableArray in the interface then synthesized in the implementation file.Then i did MyTestArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];The took the values as last post.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more careful about your memory management here.

Remember that anything that didn't begin with alloc/copy will always return you a autorelease object, meaning if you don't retain it, it will get released.

From your latest reply, you might get a leak if you have previously allocated a NSMutableArray and den replace it with a new array with the code you posted here. You might want to read up memory management in Objective C. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

Comment: In the property i did it like : @property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *MyTestArray;Then used it.But it wasn't working.But it's working in your way.How can i retain myarray object in the property?Thank you so much for the reference and nice description.I got the idea now.

Comment: the proper way to use the property inside the class is to use it with `self.` prefix. Like `self.MyTestArray` instead of just `MyTestArray`. remember if you are assigning to a property with alloc/init, always append autorelease. e.g. [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease] to prevent leaks.